# Why do 13 characters crash Chrome on a Mac

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

Why does the following string of characters crash Google Chrome on a Mac?

[image: problematic string]
<sup>The actual string can be found [on this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/munocuwoju/1)</sup>

I've read all about it but nobody has given any answer as to why it actually happens.

Does anybody actually know why this happens and can explain?

Comment: Do you have the hex values? The characters don't render at all on Android Chrome.

Comment: @ChrisJ It's `71D 718 71A 722 722 20 712 71D 72C 20 710 726 72A 71D 721`

Answer (score 1):

It is not publicly known why this happens, but Google is [aware of the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468390). If you're really interested, you could look into the crash report shown on that thread and try to investigate.

There are workarounds available by downloading certain fonts such as [Syriac](http://www.bethmardutho.org/index.php/resources/fonts.html) or [Thaana](http://www.fontspace.com/category/thaana), so the problem could be simply that the rendering of that character sequence is not supported by the default fonts installed when using Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: That's highly unlikely, considering that absence of font support with multibyte characters hasn't inflicted something as severe as browser crashes in Chromium before. If I were to take a loose guess, I'd say it might be a combination of architecture-specific Unicode handling (meaning the way Chrome interprets some script-specific character rendering is reliant on the underlying locale support of the running system, explaining why Mac OS is the one being affected). A memory allocation routine might've stubbed its toe on an edge somewhere. In either case, it's now been fixed in 41.0.2272.104